# Fail to catch SNMPv3 traps with MG-SOFT trap ringer (MIB Browser)

Tags: snmp

I use MG-SOFT MIB Browser. I want to catch SNMPv3 traps. I use the trap ringer. On one of my PC's SNMPv3  traps are not shown. SNMPv2 do.
I configured MIB Browser to catch SNMPv3 traps. They are seen in Wireshark on the same PC and they are shown in different PC in the trap ringer. Both PCs's are configured the same as far as I know (the SNMPv3 user) and have the same OS: Windows 10. I would like to understand what can be the reason?

Comment: In SNMP v3, the trap receiver machine must trust the trap sender machine and know a few settings in advance ("The difference is that SNMPv3 TRAPs use the engineID of the local application sending the trap rather than the engineID of the remote application."). That's the most tricky part of v3 protocol, so most SNMP solutions have special documentation on that (NET-SNMP uses http://www.net-snmp.org/tutorial/tutorial-5/commands/snmptrap-v3.html). So in your case, check carefully the vendor documentation to see what you missed.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for your response. But I have 2 similar PCs (at least on a first sight) and on one it is working and on another it is not. The MIB Browser tool is configured the same on both.

Comment: Then the key is in the packets you captured with Wireshark. Escalate to your network administrators and they should be able to analyze further for you. This has little to do with programming, so off topic here.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for your response. The key I believe is in the MIB-Browser tool, as the packet is OK, so at least for us it is not network administrator issue. Anyway  I understood your point. Thank you.